# On compactness of Radon measures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I'm interested in clarifying a step in the proof of the compactness theorem for Radon measures. The following exposition follows Theorem 4.16 in Simon's GMT notes which may be found in the following link: https://web.stanford.edu/class/math285/ts-gmt.pdf.

> If $\{\mu_i\}$ is a sequence of Radon measures which are locally uniformly bounded, i.e. on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for each compact $K$, we have
> $$\sup_i \mu_i(K)<\infty,$$
> then there exists a subsequence that weak star converges to some Radon measure $\mu$.

The proof is based on an application of Riez representation theorem, so $\mu$ arises by a construction of a linear functional $F$ on $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. We take a compact exhaustion of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by, say, $\{B_j\}$ a sequence of balls of radius $j$ centered at the origin. Define for $\varphi\in C_c(B_j)$,
$$F_{i,j}(\varphi):=\int_{B_j}\phi d\mu_i.$$

For each $j$, we can use Banach-Alaoglu to extract a functional $F_{j}$ arising as the limit of a subsequence in $i$. By taking successive subsequences as we increase $j$, we diagonally construct a subsequence of measures, which I reindex as $\{\mu_k\}$. Then, define $F$ as
$$F(\varphi):=\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varphi d\mu_k,$$
for $\varphi\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The proof finishes by considering Riesz representation theorem and by checking $F$ is independent of $j$ as we may just restrict our domains, and the subsequences were taken successively.

My issue is that I don't see why $F$ must be bounded. If $\text{spt}(\varphi)\subset B_j$, then
$$|F(\varphi)|=|F_j(\varphi)|=\lim_{k\to \infty}|{\int_{B_j}}\varphi d\mu_k|\leq \sup_k(\mu_k(B_j))\cdot\sup |\varphi|=C(j)\cdot\sup|\varphi|.$$
I don't understand how I arrange $C(j)\leq C<\infty$?

Comment: There is no such constant $C$ independent of $j$, but that's also not needed for a Radon measure. Such a $C$ exists if and only if the limit measure $\mu$ is finite.

Comment: Independence of j isn’t needed to show F is bounded? I thought it $C(j)\to \infty$, then the operator norm of F is infinite.

Comment: I think you are mixing things up. A Radon measure induces a continuous linear functional on the locally convex space $C_c$ in the sense of Theorem 4.14. This functional is in general not continuous with respect to the supremum norm on $C_c$ - in fact, this is the case if and only if the measure is finite.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for pointing this out, I totally glossed over it earlier! I guess this exactly is the reason why we take the following notion of convergence on $C_c$. If you could make the comment an answer, I'll accept it.